If a person borrows something and pay more than its value in loan costs, would that be the same as buying it?
If a person borrowed an item and ended up paying more than its value to keep the loan running, would that person then own the item?

Did the agreement to borrow the item include an agreement that the borrower could keep it if he paid more than its value?

There are "lease to own" contracts that explicitly say that you own the item after a certain number of payments, this is not uncommon in car leases. It's essentially an installment sale.

Are you asking about a rental agreement? Because most people don't take out a loan to borrow something, they take out a loan to buy something. Either that or they rent it. In any case the terms of the agreement should answer this question if you read them.

You will not own the item unless the contract says that you will. It will usually be clear if you have such a contract because it will be called something like a "hire purchase" rather than a loan.
Generally, when you borrow something (whether an item or a sum of money) and make regular payments in return for the loan, those payments are compensating the owner for being without the item for a particular period of time. If the lender is going to be without the item for some period and ultimately give you the item, then they're going to want to be compensated for both things.
Consider what happens when you lend $100 to your bank by placing it into an interest-bearing bank account. Let's say the bank pays you 5% interest per year. After around 14 years you've received $100 in interest. Can the bank now keep your original $100? If they did that, you'd be left with just the $100 in interest. What did you gain by depositing it for 14 years?

No, this cannot be true in general.
Suppose person A buys a house. He borrows money from the bank. He has to pay back the loan over an extended period, and he has to pay interest on the loan. As a home owner he has to pay council tax. He is also responsible for the maintenance.
His neighbor B has instead rented a house. He pays a monthly rent to the home-owner. He has an obligation to keep the place clean, but not much more than that.
After many years B realizes that he has paid more money in rent to the home-owner than A to the bank. Yet he still does not own the house. However, this is not unfair. A had more responsibilities all these years, and he is ultimately rewarded for the choices he made. B chose the easier route.
